# How to use a list of objects' name to extract some columns from their associated dataframes using loop in R?

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe

### I EDITED my question

I created a list of names of 78 objects that I want to work with them in my code using the following lines of code. Eventually, I want to apply more or less the same functions to all of them in my work

```
total = len.part * len.report  # This is equal to 78
nam.value <- list()
# Reporters and Partners are the name of countries
# Values is the name of my big dataframe which I am subsetting
for(i in Reporters) {
  for (j in Partners) {
  nam <- paste(i, "_VALUES_IMV_", j,  sep = "")
  nam.value <- c(nam.value, nam)
  assign(nam, subset(Values, PARTNER == j & REPORTER == i & FLOW_LAB == "IMPORT") )
} }
```

The above code produces the list of names in the nam.value as well as 78 objects which are dataframes each of which has 14 columns. I am trying to use a loop to extract certain columns from these 78 dataframes using the names list that I just produced. Right now, 
I have a quick and dirty solution to it which involves writing the name of all these objects down:

```
GB_VALUES_IMV_IN2 = GB_VALUES_IMV_IN[keeps]
GB_VALUES_IMV_EUEX2 = GB_VALUES_IMV_EUEX[keeps]
GB_VALUES_IMV_EUIN2 = GB_VALUES_IMV_EUIN[keeps]
IE_VALUES_IMV_IN2 = IE_VALUES_IMV_IN[keeps]
IE_VALUES_IMV_EUEX2 = IE_VALUES_IMV_EUEX[keeps]
IE_VALUES_IMV_EUIN2 = IE_VALUES_IMV_EUIN[keeps]
DE_VALUES_IMV_IN2 = DE_VALUES_IMV_IN[keeps]
DE_VALUES_IMV_EUEX2 = DE_VALUES_IMV_EUEX[keeps]
DE_VALUES_IMV_EUIN2 = DE_VALUES_IMV_EUIN[keeps]
..
..
..
```

But I am trying to use a shorter code and stop writing tens of lines of code by using a loop:

```
# The name of the columns that I want to keep and dropping the rest.
keeps = c("PRODUCT", "PERIOD","PARTNER", "INDICATOR_VALUE")
for (i in length(nam.value){
  assign(nam.value[[i]], subset(nam.value[[i]], select = keeps) ) }
```

But I get the error:

```
Error in subset.default(nam.value[[i]], select = keeps) : 
  argument "subset" is missing, with no default
```

When I put the name of each object the above code, it works perfectly but for some reason it does not accept the names in the list. I don't need to use loops necessarily but trying with lapply and sapply, still I couldn't resolve my problem. Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for this?

  `newdata <-subset(yourdata,select = c("PRODUCT", "PERIOD","PARTNER", "INDICATOR_VALUE")` not sure if I got your question

Comment: Usually `assign` is not required, could you try `newList = lapply(nam.value,function(x) nam.value[[x]][,keeps])`

Comment: @Osssan My list is just a list of names of class "character" and it is not the list of my dataframe objects. I think this is why I can't use lapply. I guess if I want to use the lapply then I need to make a  new list of my dataframe objects but I am not sure if this is going to slow down my code or make it faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `data.table` package it can be simplified to the following

Attempting to recreate your `Values` dataframe in `data.table`. If your dataframe is in a csv or database, you can either use the `fread` or `as.data.table` functions to import/convert the main Values table.

```
Values = data.table(
    'REPORTER'=c(rep('GB',3),rep('IE',3),rep('DE',3)),
    'PARTNER'=c(rep(c('IN2','EUEX2','EUIN2'),3)),
    'PRODUCT'=rep(c(1,2,3),3),
    'PERIOD'=rep(c(1,2,3)+3,3),
    'INDICATOR_VALUE'=rep(c(1,2,3)+6,3),
    'DUMMY'=c(1:9)
)
```

Creating a vector with the interaction between `REPORTER` and `PARTNER` :

```
info = with(Values,{interaction(REPORTER,PARTNER)})
info = levels(info)[info] # factor to string
```

Creating the `keeps` vector :

```
keeps = c("PRODUCT", "PERIOD","PARTNER", "INDICATOR_VALUE")
```

Loop through the `interaction` components

```
for( i in info ){
    info_list = unlist( strsplit(i,'\\.'))
    rep  = info_list[[1]]
    part = info_list[[2]]
    print( paste0(rep,'_VALUES_IMV_',part) )
    print( Values[ REPORTER == rep & PARTNER == part , .SD , .SDcols=keeps] )
}
```

Hope that helps get you in the direction you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided my Phillips works perfectly. I should look more into data tables. However, after digging more I got the answer to my own question by using still data frames. I decided to post it in case someone wants an alternative way to doing this. My solution requires a bit of modification to my code and using get() function. I decided to make a list of dataframes so that I could use lapply.

```
total = len.part * len.report # This is equal to 78
ls.df.val <- list()
for(i in Reporters) {
  for (j in Partners) {
  nam <- paste(i, "_VALUES_IMV_", j,  sep = "")
  assign(nam, subset(Values, PARTNER == j & REPORTER == i & FLOW_LAB == "IMPORT") )
  ls.df.val[[nam]] <-get(nam)
} } 

ls.df.val.keep <- lapply(ls.df.val, function(x) x[(names(x) %in% keeps)])
```